# qcow2 virtio disk partition keeps being reset

Tags: partition

I have a qcow2 disk whose virtual size is 30G

```
# qemu-img info system.qcow2.backup.2021731 
image: system.qcow2.backup.2021731
file format: qcow2
virtual size: 30G (32212254720 bytes)
disk size: 8.6G
cluster_size: 65536
Format specific information:
    compat: 1.1
    lazy refcounts: false
    refcount bits: 16
    corrupt: false
```

I attach disk using

```
# virsh attach-disk --live <instance> --subdriver qcow2 /path/to/system.qcow2
```

In the virtual machine, initially its partition size is 10G

```
# lsblk 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
vdb    252:16   0   30G  0 disk 
└─vdb1 252:17   0   10G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  374K  0 rom  
loop0    7:0    0   64M  0 loop /tmp/vm-watchdog-reset-win2k8r2-config
vda    252:0    0 97.7G  0 disk 
└─vda1 252:1    0 97.7G  0 part /
```

So I run a `resizepart` to enlarge its partition

```
# resizepart /dev/vdb 1 60817408
```

And it works when I run lsblk

```
# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
vdb    252:16   0   30G  0 disk 
└─vdb1 252:17   0   29G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  374K  0 rom  
loop0    7:0    0   64M  0 loop /tmp/vm-watchdog-reset-win2k8r2-config
vda    252:0    0 97.7G  0 disk 
└─vda1 252:1    0 97.7G  0 part /
```

but when I detach disk and re attach again `lsblk` shows that partition size is rolled back to 10G again. what could be the reason for this?

EDIT:

I tried to resize partiton by `fdisk` and it worked, so maybe I use `resizepart` incorrectly?

Comment: You need to resize the qcow2 image before resizing any partitions within it: https://www.geekpills.com/virtulization/how-to-resize-qcow2-disks-image

Comment: Sounds like it somehow failed to actually write to the image...

Comment: @ajgringo619 qcow2 image is already resized. resizepart is executed after resize...

Comment: @TomYan I try to write to it by first resize partition to a correct value and then mount and touch a file to it. what confuses me is after attach-disk again, partition size is still incorrect but the file exists....

Comment: Oh right: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/resizepart.8.html